# One website with different store views on different domains

Tags: redirect, store-view, language, domain

I found some solutions but none complete or working for me.

So I have a main website, let's call it **www.main1.com** that has different views translated in different languages: **german, italian and english**.


What I would like is to redirect the german domain **www.germandomain.com** to the german view from **www.main1.com**.


Also I want to keep the views under one website so that the flags can appear in the header.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a **redirect**, configure the redirect to go to

```
www.main1.com?___store=1
```

where `1` is the id of the German store view.

---

If you want the store view to run on the different domain (not just a redirect), you have to:

- point all domains to the Magento document root
- configure the base urls per store view
- set the environment variable `MAGE_RUN_CODE` dependent on the host name.

  Example `.htaccess` configuration:

  ```
  SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
  SetEnvIf Host germandomain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=german
  ```

  where `german` is the store code of the German store view.
- configure "Use SID" to "Yes" if the user session should work across domains.